# Como declarar um array em javascript que vai receber um array de JSON

Tags: json, angular

Dada a interface:

```
export interface Pergunta {
    id: number
    titulo: string
    opcoes:[]
}
```

Quero que o array opções receba o seu array de opçoes:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "titulo": "Qual o seu comportamento em relação aos seus investimentos?",
    "opcoes": [
      {
        "description": "Preservar meu dinheiro sem correr risco"
      },
      {
        "description": "Ganhar mais dinheiro, assumindo riscos moderados"
      },
      {
        "description": "Ganhar mais dinheiro, assumindo riscos agressivo"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export interface Pergunta {
    id: number;
    titulo: string;
    opcoes: Opcao[];
}

export interface Opcao {
    description: string;
}
```

Essa seria a maneira mais correta de receber seus dados

Comment: É, você está declarando um valor numérico como String.... o @Marcus Dacorréggio está correto.

Comment: Marcus pq a public opcoes: Array<TipoDeOpcoes>;  seria errado?

Comment: @marcus como que eu chamo esse array opcoes no *ngfor de array de pergunta ?

Comment: Se você está usando Angular 2+ você pode chamar utilizando `*ngFor="let opcao of pergunta.opcoes"`

Comment: Tipo

<section class="content">
  <div class="row">

          <div *ngFor="let pergunta of perguntas" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <app-pergunta [pergunta]="pergunta"></app-pergunta>
              
          </div>
        </div>
</section>

Comment: Dentro do seu component `app-pergunta` você provavelmente terá o component `app-pergunta-opcao` ou algo do tipo, no qual você irá utilizar o *ngFor que passei acima

Comment: @TiagoTiede eu acredito que para o Angular fazer o deserialize do objeto o `Array` não serviria, teria que ser `TipoDeOpcoes[]`

Comment: Entendo. O estranho que fiz um pocket e foi sem estresse aqui. Bom o importante é aprender e ajudar o amigo :D

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a melhor solução é você 'tipar' o array do atributo **opcoes**.
Em alguns casos quando você não fazer esse processo, você pode utilizar um *array* de *any*.
Por exemplo:

```
public opcoes: Array<any>;
```

Contudo acredito que a melhor solução para o seu problema seria algo assim:

```
export interface Pergunta {
    public id: number
    public titulo: string;
    public opcoes: Array<TipoDeOpcoes>;   } 

    export interface TipoDeOpcoes {
            public description: string   
}
```

Comment: ai me dá erro de PerguntasComponent.html:5 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'